# Existence of amorphous sets

Tags: set-theory

An amorphous set is an infinite set which is not the disjoint union of two infinite subsets.

I have read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set) that proofs of the consistency of amorphous sets with Zermelo-Fraenkel were obtained.

Where can I find a proof of the existence of a model of ZF in which an amorphous set exists?

Comment: Wikipedia cite its sources, did you look there?

Comment: I cannot get access to the cited article

Comment: http://h.web.umkc.edu/halle/relfin/orderfinite-revisions.pdf is open access it seems, might have info there, from wiki

Comment: @Alan at the end of page 20 it says that (ZF+"there exists an amorphous set") is equiconsistent with ZF by remarks above. But I don't understand why...